# Job fails when loading data from server1 to server 2 inside SQL Server agent

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I have created a ssis package to load data from server 1 table1 to server 2 table2. This package is running fine inside the business intelligence studio. But the issue is , when I schedule this package in SQL server agent as a job, the package execution is failing.

The error I am getting is

> SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E4D. Description: "Login failed for user 'Domain\Server1$' .
>   Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.
>   The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "Server2.Database2" failed with error code 0xC0202009.

Please help me to fix the issue. I am using SQL Server 2014

Thank you very much for your time and help!

Comment: Does the user have the correct rights on both servers? My guess is the service running the job agent doesn't have the correct rights on one of the servers. Change the run as option in the job to someone you know for sure has sufficient rights on bother servers to test it.

Comment: @Wes Palmer. Thank you very much . I will try your solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is a security / permissions issue.  Update the SQL Server Agent job to use an account which has sufficient permissions to complete all of the actions inside the SSIS package.

### Explanation

The package completes succesfully when executed from Business Intelligence Studio, because that execution is running under you credentials.  It is running as you.  When you run the package from SQL Service Agent job, it is NOT using your credentials.  Instead it is using account 'Domain\Server1$' and that account does NOT have sufficient rights against Server2.Database2 to complete all of the package actions.

To solve this, you could update the security on Server2.Database2 and allow 'Domain\Server1$' to perform the same actions as you, but that is unadvised.  Instead, best practice here is to establish an SSIS proxy account.  Here is a [good article](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/setting-up-your-sql-server-agent-correctly/) discussing how to go about that.  After you have established this proxy account, grant the new proxy account sufficient permissions to complete the actions inside of your SSIS package and your error message will go away.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much Troy Witthoeft. I will try your solution